# How do I remove duplicate icon from Ubuntu dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, jar

After using

```
jar xvf <filename>
```

command to unzip a file I suddenly got a second duplicate of the Files icon on my dock as you can see on the picture:
[image: screenshot]

Clicking the "duplicate" icon at the bottom opens a new files window as normal but only accessible by the "real" icon as you can see from the dots aside the "real" icon. I do not have an option to remove the duplicate icon from the favorites but I do have "add to favorites" option which is quite strange. To give you more details, these duplicate icons do not appear on the dash if I search for "files".

Comment: Can you "unpin" that second icon?

Comment: The files icon which is on the 3rd place is "unpinnable" however if I click the second to last files icon I get another files icon on the dock as depicted on the screenshot.